# How to populate a 2D array with random elements?

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array, typeerror

For a Memory game, I'm trying to randomly populate a 2D array with letters.

The grid is `size` × `size` and each letter occurs twice.

This is my code so far. I don't understand why it is giving an error

```
alpha = ("A".."Z").to_a
letters_range = alpha[0...size*size/2]
chosen_letters = (letters_range + letters_range).shuffle

(0...size).each do |row|
    (0...size).each do |col|
        letter = chosen_letters.select
        @grid[row][col] = Card.new(letter)
        letter_idx = chosen_letters.index(letter)
        chosen_letters.delete_at(letter_idx)  #error line
    end
end
```

Comment: `chosen_letters.select` returns an enumerator, not a letter as you might expect. Because of that `chosen_letters.index(letter)` returns `nil`...

Comment: forgot to notice I have used select instead of sample. Different set of eyes, always works. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hint: size is undefined in line two of your example. Do you mean alpha.size?

Comment: Looks like it's the intended dimension of the grid being made. This isn't a complete [MRE].

Comment: @spickermann, size is the size of the grid. Was trying to populate grid for Memory game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chosen_letters` is an array containing single-character strings.

When running `letter = chosen_letters.select`, you may assume that [`Array#select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-select) returns a random element. However, when not passing it a block, it returns an `Enumerator`. As such, your `letter` variable does not contain an element from the `chosen_letter` array and thus, an index for this object can not be found, resulting in `letter_idx` to be `nil`.

To fix this, you may want to use a more appropriate statement to fetch an element, e.g. [`Array#pop`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-pop) to return and remove the last element from the array.

Answer (score 0):

Since `chosen_letters` is already shuffled, you don't have to pick a *random* element. Instead you can just [`pop`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Array.html#pop-method) the last or [`shift`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Array.html#shift-method) the first element off the array which makes your loop a lot simpler:

```
(0...size).each do |row|
  (0...size).each do |col|
    letter = chosen_letters.shift
    @grid[row][col] = Card.new(letter)
  end
end
```

It might be a little cleaner to start with an array of *cards*, e.g. by creating a pair of two cards for each letter:

```
cards = letters_range.flat_map { |letter| [Card.new(letter), Card.new(letter)] }

cards.shuffle!
```

You can then assign the cards to the grid via:

```
(0...size).each do |row|
  (0...size).each do |col|
    @grid[row][col] = cards.shift
  end
end
```

or you could build the `@grid` right out of the array via [`each_slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Enumerable.html#each_slice-method):

```
@grid = cards.each_slice(size).to_a
```